# NameError: name 'mobile' is not defined

Tags: python, function, class

```
class mobile:
    def __init__(self,brandname,color,isjack):

        self.brand=brandname
        self.color=color
        self.isjack=isjack

    def calling(self):
        print('calling')

    def cameraclick(self):
        print('picture is clicked')

    def message(self):
        print('message_sent')

    def main():

        m1=mobile('apple','black',False)
        print(m1.brand)
        print(m1.color)
        print(m1.isjack)
        m1.calling()
        m1.cameraclick()
        m1.message()   

        print("-------------------")

        m2=mobile('samsung','grey',False)
        print(m2.brand)
        print(m2.color)    
        print(m2.isjack)
        
    if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

I wrote a basic code to check why was i getting the name error. if anyone could help?

Comment: Reduce the `main` and if statement by one indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are u doing?

This is happening bcs of indentation mistakes on the code!

`Python uses indentation to indicate a block of code.`

if `main` lives inside `class mobile` block it will only be callable if u prepend it with the `mobile` keyword when calling it

So u need to unindent the `def main():` and `if __name__ == '__main__':`  method and to the root level.

```py
class Mobile:
    def __init__(self, brandname, color,isjack):
        self.brand=brandname
        self.color=color
        self.isjack=isjack

    def calling(self):
        print('calling')

    def cameraclick(self):
        print('picture is clicked')

    def message(self):
        print('message_sent')

def main():
    m1 = Mobile("apple", "black", False)
    print(m1.brand)
    print(m1.color)
    print(m1.isjack)
    m1.calling()
    m1.cameraclick()
    m1.message()

    print("-------------------")

    m2 = Mobile("samsung", "grey", False)
    print(m2.brand)
    print(m2.color)
    print(m2.isjack)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

tip:

- ur class should ne named under the PascalCase rules

Answer (score 2):

Check your indentation. As it is right now, your `main` function is a (static) method of your `mobile` class. This means that method and everything inside it gets read *before* the class definition for `mobile` is complete. Thus, the interpreter does not "know" `mobile` yet.

You should also reduce the indentation for this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```